# CamanJS individual channel saturation like Photoshop/GIMP

Tags: javascript, image-processing, html5-canvas, camanjs

Using CamanJS, how can we manipulate individual color channel saturation like GIMP or Photoshop?

For example, if I decrease Red color saturation it only reduces the saturation of the Red channel. Here is the before and after image.

[image: Before Saturation] [image: After Saturation]

In GIMP there is functionality to change saturation/hue for individual colors.
[image]

**Please let me know how can we achieve this using CamanJS or any other Canvas manipulation javascript library?**

Comment: Can you please be a little more specific with your question? Do you want to re-create the image using functions or something else?

Comment: @Vakore, I want to change individual color channel saturation. Like in the above image where I have reduced the saturation of the Red channel. I want to apply this color correction to the original image using CamanJS or HTML 5 Canvas